# how to handle if data is null in flutter like this image? im so confuse when data is null always show error

Tags: json, flutter, dart, parsing

[this is sampele of my json response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HOlL1.png)

[always show error like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzVkf.png)

Comment: pls add some code details

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use null safety in your model class.

```
class Profile{
  String? photo;

  Profile({
    this.photo,
  });

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'photo': photo,
    };
  }

  factory Profile.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> map) {
    return Profile(
      photo: map["profile"]['photo'] ?? "",
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding null keep them as empty string
ex-

```
{
 'class':''
}
```